# Anomaly detection with mean shift sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mean, shift, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to use mean shift from sklearn to find anomalies and outliers in a dataset. The datasets are signal values from sensors. I have a training dataset to train the algorithm and a test dataset containing dummy anomalies. My problem is that when I use the predict method on test dataset, mean shift doesn't label anomalies with -1 or any other value that indicates anomalies or outliers but associates them with valid cluster. 
Here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
from sklearn import preprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':

    train= pd.read_csv("train.csv")

    test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(train)

    bandwidth = estimate_bandwidth(train, n_jobs=-1)

    ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth,n_jobs=-1)

    ms.fit(scaler.transform(train))

    prediction = ms.predict(scaler.transform(test))

    test["cluster"] = prediction

    print np.unique(prediction)
```

here first 5 row training dataset:

```
                 A                B               C
0               300               0              200  
1               300               0              200   
2               300               0              350   
3               300               1              350   
4               400               1              350
```

here first 5 row test dataset with dummy anomalies:

```
                 A                B               C
0               300               0              200  
1               300               0              200   
2               300               0              350   
3         100000000       100000000        100000000   
4               400               1              350
```

what can i do to detect anomalies in test dataset?

Comment: Maybe first clean the data using anamoly detection: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html

Comment: it uses another algorithm, not mean shift

Comment: Yes I know. But mean shift at the time of predicting]() will only assign the cluster closest to the point. So in case of outlier, however large those distances are, the smallest among them will be assigned as the cluster for that point and that cluster will be from the valid clusters. So there's no way in mean shift to handle such cases, unless you make some changes to the algorithm for assigning the clusters or introduce more such outlier values which hopefully gets assigned a new cluster of their own and not interfere with actual data. Hope you get my point.

Comment: yes, i get it. will the problem be the same eventually with birch, DBSCAN or affinity propagation?

Comment: Yes I think so.